# Is there a .NET API equivalent to the "Build 2.0" REST API for TFS 2015?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

The [REST API Reference for VS Team Services and TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview) page separates the "Build 1.0" and "Build 2.0" APIs.

It seems like such a difference also exists in the .NET API because running the following code only lists the "old" XAML build definitions and not the new ones.

```
var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsurl"));
var buildServer = tpc.GetService<IBuildServer>();
var def = buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions("Project Name"); // Finds only XAML definitions
```

Is there a new DLL I can reference to write equivalent code that will work with the new TFS or is the web API all there is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildDefinition
```

in:

```
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi, Version=14.0.0.0
```

Which can be accessed through:

```
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClient
```

Simplest way to add it to your project is using the [Nuget Package:](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! If anyone's looking for the dll on a machine where TFS is not installed, it can be found in the Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools folder if you happen to have that installed.

Comment: Best way to add it, is through the new nuget package. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ExtendedClient