# attach workitem to build via REST API

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild

I want to attach a work item on tfs to a build. i am reading SVN logs which contain the work item number and try to update the actual build to attach them.

```
workitems.Add(workItemStore.GetWorkItem(workitemid));
buildDetail.Information.AddAssociatedWorkItems(workitems.ToArray());
```

When I try to hit `buildDetail.Information.Save();` or `buildDetail.Save();`, I get an `AccessDeniedException`.

See [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157494/tfs-user-needs-permission-to-update-build-information).

So I wanted to try with REST...
After loads of pages on MSDN, I concluded there is no .NET Client Library that takes care of builds. It looks like my only option is to patch a json into the TFS:

> PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version={version}

How do I add the workitems the right way?

EDIT: I've found an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34500703/5384879) which mentioned a dll in the TFS namespace which has the same capabilities like the call from above. Unluckily, it's not refered in MSDN. Same problem here: no way to add workitems.

To spread the issue and adress it to MS: [Patrick has created a post on uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15613161-attach-workitem-to-build-via-rest-api)

UPDATE:

I managed to link a build in the work item. Here is an approach in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23):

```
var json = new JsonPatchDocument
            {
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = "/relations/-",
                    Value = new WorkItemRelation()
                            {
                                Rel = "ArtifactLink",
                                Url = build.Uri.ToString()
                            }
                }
            };

var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json-patch+json");
client.UploadData(
    options.CollectionUri + "/_apis/wit/workitems/" + workitemid + "?api-version=1.0",
    "PATCH",
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json)));
```

But there is still no direct binding in the build:
[image: build]

And the work items says `unknown executable linktype`
[image: work item]

According to the message given in the workitem, I assume that I am using the false [linktype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.proxy.workitemrelation.linktypeid(v=vs.100).aspx). Does anybody have a reference for me, what types I am able to and should use?

URI UPDATE:
I am already using the mentioned uri:
[image: json]

**MINOR SOLUTION:**

I had to add the name "Build" to the Attributes of the patch. I still does not recognize it in the build itself but for now, I can work with the link as build type.

```
var json = new JsonPatchDocument
            {
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = "/relations/-",
                    Value = new WorkItemRelation()
                            {
                                Rel = "ArtifactLink",
                                Url = build.Uri.ToString()
                                Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                                {
                                    { "name", "Build" },
                                    { "comment", build.Result.ToString() }
                                }
                            }
                }
            };
```

Comment: What's the type of your build? XAML or vNext?

Comment: See my answer for details.

Comment: You need to use build uri, you can also use `$env:BUILD_BUILDURI` in a power shell script. More detail info, please see my update answer.

Comment: hi @Patrick-MSFT, I am already using this uri. I've updated the post for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a workitem to a build by updating the workitem to add a relation link to the build via Rest API. Refer to this link for details: [Add a Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-a-link).

After you add a link to the build in the workitem, the workitem would be show in the build summary.

Following is the content sample of the body,

```
[
    {
        "op": "test",
        "path": "/rev",
        "value": "2"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value":
        {
            "rel": "ArtifactLink",
            "url": "vstfs:///Build/Build/12351"
        }
    }
]
```

Add code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace AssociateWorkItemToBuild
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
                     ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", "password"))));

                string Url = "https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workitems/149?api-version=1.0";
                StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
                body.Append("[");
                body.Append("{");
                body.Append("\"op\":\"add\",");
                body.Append(" \"path\":\"/relations/-\",");
                body.Append("\"value\":");
                body.Append("{");
                body.Append("\"rel\": \"ArtifactLink\",");
                body.Append("\"url\": \"vstfs:///Build/Build/12596\"");
                body.Append("}");
                body.Append("}");
                body.Append("]");

                var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, Url)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(body.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8,
                                    "application/json-patch+json")
                };

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to bind the link in the work item, but there is still a minor problem. I update my question. Thank you so far!

Comment: still doesn't recognize it as linked build

Comment: This doesn't work, I am getting ""Artifact links must have a valid name specified"

https://***.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workitems/49469?api-version=5.0
[
    {
        "op":  "test",
        "path":  "/rev",
        "value":  "3"
    },
    {
        "op":  "add",
        "path":  "/relations/-",
        "value":  {
                      "rel":  "ArtifactLink",
                      "url":  "vstfs:///Build/Build/105702"
                  }
    }
]

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Just as *Eddie* replied, you could add a workitem to a build by updating the workitem to add a relation link to the build via Rest API.

About **LinkType** there has been a clear demo  in *Eddie's* answer. You need to use **build uri**.

**The format needs to be** `vstfs:///Build/Build/8320`

The BuildUri for the TFS Build tasks is a property that needs to be set so that those tasks can communicate with the server about the build they are performing actions for.

---

You can also use `$env:BUILD_BUILDURI` in a powershell script, more detail info and ways you can also refer this blog from MSDN: [Build association with work Items in vNext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/09/build-association-with-work-items-in-vnext/) Finally will get :

[image]